# I run the android11 emulator in arm export a fault:qemu-system-aarch64: PCI bus not available for hda

Tags: android, qt, emulation, qemu, pci

The following is the details. My environment is the latest android studio, and os is ubuntu 18.04. It exported the fault and do not show anything in screen.

```
$ emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_30<
emulator: Android emulator version 30.3.5.0 (build_id 7033400) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
added library /home/astar/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:288: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
qemu-system-aarch64: PCI bus not available for hda
段错误 (核心已转储)
```